# Symfony horizontal radio buttons

Tags: symfony, radio-button, twig

I am trying to get radio buttons on the same line. The closest solutions I have found so far are these:
[Bootstrap 3: does form-horizontal work for radio buttons with a control-label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819010/bootstrap-3-does-form-horizontal-work-for-radio-buttons-with-a-control-label)

[Radio buttons Horizontal Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072364/radio-buttons-horizontal-alignment)
But they do not use symfony. Is there a built in solution for symfony forms?
What would be the easiest way?
By the way, I still need some other radio buttons to be vertical.

```
<div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 5px'>
    <div style='white-space:nowrap'>
         <div class='col-xs-5'>
             <div class='col-xs-5'>
                 {{ form_label(form.mNec, 'Necrotising enterocolitis', {'label_attr':{'style':'margin-top:3px'}})}}
             </div>
             <div class='col-xs-2' style='margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 120px'>
                  {{ form_widget(form.mNec, {'attr':{'style':'width:60px'}})}}
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>


->add('mNec', 'choice', array(
    'choices'=>array(
    'absent'=>1,
    'suspected'=>2,
    'proven (positive x-ray)'=>3),
    'choices_as_values'=>true,
    'expanded'=>true))
```

Comment: What happens when you add those styles to your template?

Comment: Do you mean tyle='margin-bottom and style='white-space:nowrap' ?

Comment: Whatever they are. Twig allows to add stylesheets, so why use inline styles?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do it in this concrete case? The styles I am using are not related to the direction of my radio buttons, which is the question I have. I welcome any advice though. Could you be then so nice to show me an easy way to get some of the radio buttons horizontal? I was wishing something in DataType like expanded-horizontal=>true but I guess it only exits in my dreams.

Comment: I cannot help you with real examples, but still can help you update your question to be easier to answer for those with expertise. Have you managed to do whatever you need with lain html+css+bootstrap? If yes, add that code to your question and (maybe) rephrase it so that it asked more about applying that code to twig template.

Comment: Has this page been useful to you? http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Comment: I am already using {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %} but it does nothing on the radio buttons. And in that link, I do not find a solution. But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So finally the answer is quite simple.

In form.html.twig

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <td>Some text</td>
  <td>{{ form_widget(form.variable[0])}}</td>
  <td>{{ form_widget(form.variable[1])}}</td>
  <td>{{ form_widget(form.variable[2])}}</td>  
</tr>

</table>
```

With Datatype.php

```
->add('variable', 'choice', array(
    'choices'=>array(
    'choice1'=>0,
    'choice2'=>1,
    'choice3'=>2),
    'choices_as_values'=>true,
    'expanded'=>true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override a single form widget by using [customizing an individual field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)

```
{% block _nameOfYourForm_mNec_entry_row %}

{% endblock %}
```

But by the way of you are using `style` attributes I think the problem is more related to a css problem.

Comment: And what do I need to write in the customization in order to make the radio buttons horizontal? And by the way, what is the problem in using style attributes that way, modularization or something? As long as it does not create erros, I am fine with that. I just want my radio buttons to be horizontal. How can I concretely do it?